# observablecollection question

Tags: c#, .net, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class/structure like the one given below

> public class FileDetails
>       {
>           public FileDetails()
>           {
>           }
>
> ```
>     public PrintFile PrintFileDetails { get; set; }
>     public Boolean IsSelected { get; set; }
>     public DateTime UploadTime { get; set; }
>     public long FileSize { get; set; }
>     public UploadTypes TypeOfUpload { get; set; }
>     public DateTime DownloadStartTime {get;set;}
>     public DateTime DownloadEndTime {get;set;}
>     public bool ShouldDownload{get;set;}
>
> }
> ```

In the above snippet `PrintFile` is defined in a XSD. I am planning to deploy this structure inside a `ObservableConnection`.  If I implement `NotifypropertychangedFileDetails` will the items under `PrintFileDetails` also able to reap benefits of `INotifypropertychanged`.  I believe i cannot implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` as it is shared among other programmers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, each object must implement INotifyPropertyChanged itself.  The PrintFile object does not benefit from the fact that the FileDetails object implements an interface.

Also, if you are generating these classes from an XSD, you can tell the generator to generate the classes with INotifyPropertyChanged implementation automatically using the /enableDataBinding command line switch on XSD.EXE.

Footnote:  Putting objects that implement INotifyPropertyChanged into an ObservableCollection won't have any magical effects.  Changes made to the objects in the collection will not fire the collection's PropertyChanged event (unless you write the code to do so).  The collection's PropertyChanged event only fires if a property of the collection object changes.

In most cases, you're using an observable collection because you want to data bind it to WPF or Silverlight UI elements and you want the UI to update itself automatically when the data changes.  The data binding system will notice if the objects in the collection implement IPropertyNotifyChanged and will attach to the PropertyChanged events automatically so that the UI will know when the data changes.

Comment: Thanks, if i use /enableDataBinding will it generate INotifyPropertyChanged  for all items inside the xsd? Is it possible to generate  INotifyPropertyChanged  for a particular item in XSD?

Comment: XSD supports specifying which elements to emit class types for using the /e switch.  I suppose you could run XSD twice, once for the classes you don't want property change notifications on, and once for the classes you do want property change notifications on, and then splice the source files together.  This is a lot of hand work that will have to be repeated every time you generate from XSD.  It would be much simpler just to gen property notifications on everything.